# My Tomcat RewriteRules are not being read properly

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8

Testing a basic rule which should redirect all traffic to index.cfm$id=1 and I just can't seem to get it to work.

The rule as defined

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.cfm?id=$1
```

I can confirm that it is being read by Tomcat as per the logs

I tried to make it work with Tuckey Rewrite before as well with not luck.

**Edit** : configuration

```
<Context path="" docBase="d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Did you enable the `RewriteValve` as said in the [doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html) ? Why redirect to index.cfm and not to /index.cfm (although I am not sure this would change anything there) ? Did you see you are creating an infinite loop as your pattern matches everything including the redirection result ?

Comment: This is my configuration <Context path="" docBase="d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\">
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
                </Context>   What do you recommend I use intead of ^/(.*)$  I've also tried ^([^/]+)/?$, which isn't working for me.